# Problem in understanding a concept of direct sum.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the direct sum of $W_{1}, W_{2}, ... , W_{k}$ then can we say that $\dim W = \dim W_{1} + \dim W_{2} + ... + \dim W_{k}$?

In particular for if $W$ is the direct sum of $W_{1}, W_{2}, W_{3}$ then how can I show that $(W_{1} \oplus W_{2}) \cap W_{3} = \{0\}$?

As far as I know the above result is not necessarily true.For instance, if I take three lines in $\mathbb R^{2}$ then leftern side of the above equality gives $W_{3} \neq \{0\}$ though $W_{1} \cap W_{3} = W_{2} \cap W_{3} = \{0\}$.Instead if I assume $W_{1}, W_{2}, W_{3}$ to be independent then the equality is quite easy to prove.I don't know what's the actual fact.So please help me in understanding this concept.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By the term "direct sum", I take it you mean that given two vector spaces spanned by sets $A, B$ and $A \cap B = \{0\}$ then $$A \oplus B = \{v \ | \ v = a + b\}$$
And the operation is well defined. I think the main confusion is that you may not be seeing the direct sum as well defined. By conventions:
$$U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus U_3 \oplus U_4 = (((U_1 \oplus U_2) \oplus U_3) \oplus U_4)$$
So you need to be careful to avoid abusve of notation. When you write multiple direct sums, that is what you are implying. By that clarity, we can answer your question fairly easy.

Concerning your first question, yes you can say that that $$dim(A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus \ .... ) = dimA + dimB + dimC + ...$$

Since if $V \cap W = \{0\}$, then if $\alpha$ spans $V$ and $\beta$ spans $W$, then the set $\alpha \cup \beta$ is also a set of linearly independent vectors.

I'm sure you can see why the second result follows as well.

Comment: But how can the formula for dimension be obtained?In particular if $V$ be a vector space which is the direct sum of three of it's subspaces $W_{1}, W_{2}, W_{3}$ i.e. if $V = W_{1} \oplus W_{2} \oplus W_{3}$ where $W_{i} \cap W_{j} = \{0\}$ for $i \neq j$.Then $\dim (W_{1} \oplus W_{2} \oplus W_{3}) = \dim (W_{1} \oplus W_{2}) + \dim W_{3} - \dim ((W_{1} \oplus W_{2}) \cap W_{3}) \neq \dim W_{1} + \dim W_{2} + \dim W_{3}$ always if we take three subspaces of $\mathbb R^{2}$ as three distinct straight lines passing through origin.

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong in my conception.

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood the concept of direct sum.What is actually the concept of direct sum $W_{1} \oplus W_{2} \oplus ... \oplus W_{k}$ is that $W_{j} \cap (W_{1} \oplus W_{2} \oplus ... \oplus W_{j-1} \oplus W_{j+1} \oplus ... \oplus W_{k}) = \{0\}$, for each $j = 1, 2, ... , k$ or in other words $W_{1} \oplus W_{2} \oplus ... \oplus W_{k}$ is a direct sum iff the set of subspaces $\{W_{i} : i = 1, 2, ... , k \}$ is independent.In my previous comment $W_{1} \oplus W_{2} \oplus W_{3}$ is not a valid direct sum since $((W_{1} \oplus W_{2}) \cap W_{3}) = W_{3} \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee., precisely